# Best approach to reload page (not from cache) using Apache and Angular

Tags: angular, apache, web, caching

I created Angular 6 app and hosting it using Apache on a remote server.
Created a build with `ng build --prod`.

I noticed that when making changes and updating an html file - the page is being loaded from a cache and not from a new version of a file that is placed in Apache folder (using default configuration in Apache and nothing in Meta tags in HTML pages yet).

How to force reloading page on a client browser but only when there is a new version of the same page? (new changes to an existing site)

What are the best practices?

Comment: Try on windows: `CTRL + F5` or `CMD + R` on mac to refresh without using the browser's cache.

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking about other users that should get refreshed page automatically if something gets changed.

Comment: @kemp same here. CTRL+F5 is not an option. My system have many users spread acros the internet. I can't send they an email asking to refresh at every deploy.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are asking this question for the production environment not for development purpose.

If this is the case, then you can check the following:

1. index.html file is not getting updated.
2. check what cache expiration is getting set on the browser. It must be `no-cache`.
3. How are you generating the building the code. If using angular-cli then the `ng build` will create a the chunk names with hash and it is different each time when the content is changed.
4. check the cache header for lazy loaded module

Comment: Ideally would like for both Dev and Prod to be refreshed (from end user point of view) soon as new feature is added (and index file or other files are modified).

Comment: What are you getting in the Response Header for the `cache-contro` and `expires`?

It should be `cache-control: no-cache` and `expires: -1`

Comment: I guess the apache server might be setting something different and that's why the browser is loading from cache.

Comment: If  `expires: -1` for your index file then the browser will never cache it and always download from server.

Comment: This is all under Header -> Headers -> Response Headers (for the main page url - there are other parts of the page in the list as well): `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Tue, 09 Oct 2018 19:10:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Oct 2018 16:35:36 GMT
ETag: "946-577ce53c9a03f"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age: 0`

Comment: You are getting `304` from your apache server. Meaning that the index.html is not changed.

Comment: Google how to set set cache setting for file/dir in apache

Comment: I am getting now `304`. Should I try to change something on a web page (index.html) and expect a different than `304`?

Comment: not on webpage but on apache conf setting. Your endgoal is to set the cache-control header. Which can be done via apache conf.

I don't know how configure apache cache header

Comment: Ok, but to prove if is Html (Angular) side or Apache side - what test can I perform to confirm 100%? (e.g. change index.html and expect different header details once open a web page?)

Comment: just check in your browser network tab for cache control response header. (either for index.html  item or your domain name, generally the 1st item in network tab).

Comment: Idea is that the index.html must never be cache because this file is very small so downloading it not problem also this file trigger other file to download.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Hash Angular files while building**

**Angular** has a built in hashing mechanism to ensure updated files are not cached. To activate this functionality you have to add the property `"outputHasing": "all"` to the build configurations in your angular.json file.
Alternatively you can build your project with the command: `ng build --output-hashing=all`

**2) Add server side Cache-Control headers**

As @Khalid mentionned, Angular does not ensure the index.html file isn't cached. Server-side response headers can take up this task. Cache-Control is a header that you can configure on your web server to add to all outgoing requests, which will tell the browser and CDNs how to cache your content.

On **Apache** you should set these cache control headers in your main configuration file 'httpd.conf'. In case you can't access this file due to hosting limitations you can set it in your '.htaccess' file. To not cache the index.html file use following cache control headers:

```
#Initialize mod_rewrite
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  FileETag None
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

NB: Make sure that the mod_headers are enabled in your main configuration file. Following line should be uncommented (without the #).

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

While calling the latest version of your page (f.ex. by refreshing without using cached content `CTRL+SHIFT+F5`) you should now see these cache control headers in your response headers. You can verify these headers in the Inspect > Network tab in your browser.

**3) Handle previously cached files**

All versions of your index.html file that were cached in your clients browser -before you added the new cache control headers- will still be cached. To overcome this issue you should use different URL's. This can be done by using a new domain name (as long as you do not care about SEO) or by adding a URL parameter (without touching SEO).

After building your Angular project as described above and adding this configuration on your Apache web server, users will always get the newest version of your page.

Comment: The problem is not hashed JS files. The problem is index.html. As it name is the same, it will not be refreshed and will keep loading old JS files from cache even the new ones are there.

Comment: That is correct. Step 2 (web server configuration) and 3 (handling previously cached files - cf. the index.html file you are talking about) explain how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you build do this:

```
ng build --output-hashing=all
```

This should prevent changed files from caching.

Comment: Jesus! Again.... this will hash only JS files not index.html. When index.html is the same, it will not be refreshed and therefore it willl keep loading old JS files EVEN HASHED.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AOT Production build, by default have hashing enabled.

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: Used exactly this way but it is still getting cached old version of index.html file.

Comment: this will hash only JS files not index.html. When index.html is the same, it will not be refreshed and therefore it willl keep loading old JS files EVEN HASHED

Answer (score 0):

When using a production build `ng build --prod`, the cli will create a bundle with a hash value attached to each of your angular files. So if you ensure your index is not cached, it will refer to the files with the hashes. If the files have not changed, their hashes will be the same, and so it will load them from the cache. If they change, it will attempt to load the new files.

The remaining thing is to ensure that the index.html file is not cached, and this can be done by sending the no-cache headers, or using a dynamic file (e.g. php, jsp, ...) instead of *.html.

Comment: Do yo have example of `no-cache` headers?

Comment: This answer goes into great details of how to set the no-cache headers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers